# Using NOT LIKE to select a list of numbers not performing as expected - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract a list of serial numbers, where their corresponding part number can NEVER have an `-INTERNAL` marking.

The way my construction company makes production orders is that a single serial number can be transitioned to a different part number across x orders. I am trying to track ONLY the serial numbers that have NEVER had an `-INTERNAL` notation on any of its part numbers.

Below is an example of the data I am working with:

```
| Serial | Make_Order_Number |   Part_Number  |
|:------:|:-----------------:|:--------------:|
|   400  |       MO321       |      NB332     |
|   400  |       MO333       |      NB333     |
|   400  |       MO311       | NB334-INTERNAL |
|   92   |       MO222       |      NB122     |
|   92   |       MO299       |      NB123     |
|   92   |       MO212       |      NB124     |
|   545  |       MO214       |      NB092     |
|   774  |       MO215       | NB093-INTERNAL |
|   774  |       MO200       | NB093-INTERNAL |
|   774  |       MO218       |      NB833     |
|   987  |       MO110       |      NB741     |
```

Ideally, I would like to get:

```
| Serial |
|:------:|
|   92   |
|   545  |
|   987  |
```

I have tried writing

```
SELECT DISTINCT Serial
FROM tblParts
WHERE Part_Number NOT LIKE '%-INTERNAL%'
```

but that yields me:

```
| Serial |
|:------:|
|   92   |
|   400  |    
|   545  |
|   774  |
|   987  |
```

because, at one point, `serial 400` *did* have a part number that met that condition. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Serial
FROM tblParts
WHERE Serial 
NOT IN 
(SELECT Serial 
FROM tblParts 
WHERE Part_Number 
LIKE '%-INTERNAL%')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this yields the same result as before.

Comment: No problem. Still same result. I think that's because a single serial number can have a part number that is both an `interval` and a non interval.

Comment: Someone may very likely beat me to it, but I'll load this up real quick and see if I can't get it...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a self-join, by using a conditional sum, e.g.:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 400 serial, 'MO321' make_order_number, 'NB332' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 400 serial, 'MO333' make_order_number, 'NB333' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 400 serial, 'MO311' make_order_number, 'NB334-INTERNAL' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 92 serial, 'MO222' make_order_number, 'NB122' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 92 serial, 'MO299' make_order_number, 'NB123' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 92 serial, 'MO212' make_order_number, 'NB124' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 545 serial, 'MO214' make_order_number, 'NB092' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 774 serial, 'MO215' make_order_number, 'NB093-INTERNAL' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 774 serial, 'MO200' make_order_number, 'NB093-INTERNAL' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 774 serial, 'MO218' make_order_number, 'NB833' part_number FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 987 serial, 'MO110' make_order_number, 'NB741' part_number FROM dual)
SELECT serial
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY serial
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN part_number LIKE '%-INTERNAL%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
ORDER BY serial;

    SERIAL
----------
        92
       545
       987
```

This works by putting 1 if the part number contains "-INTERNAL", and 0 otherwise, then summing up those numbers for each serial and excluding any that have a sum > 0.

This query may or may not be faster than the self-join query - you should test both against your data, and see which one works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can `GROUP BY serial` and filter by the groups `HAVING` no instances with an internal part.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblParts ( Serial, Make_Order_Number, Part_Number ) AS
  SELECT 400, 'MO321', 'NB332' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 400, 'MO333', 'NB333' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 400, 'MO311', 'NB334-INTERNAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  92, 'MO222', 'NB122' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  92, 'MO299', 'NB123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  92, 'MO212', 'NB124' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 545, 'MO214', 'NB092' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 774, 'MO215', 'NB093-INTERNAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 774, 'MO200', 'NB093-INTERNAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 774, 'MO218', 'NB833' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 987, 'MO110', 'NB741' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Serial
FROM   tblParts
GROUP BY Serial
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN Part_Number LIKE '%-INTERNAL%' THEN 1 END ) = 0
```

**Output**:

```
| SERIAL |
| -----: |
|    987 |
|    545 |
|     92 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2258a63045aa13ba939a6353e48db197)*